# UISlider not working smoothly in MPMusicPlayerController in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, media-player, xcode4.5

I ham new to programming i have made a Music Player in i-phone using MPMusicPlayerController,i am able to achieve that but i am stuck in scrubbing the audio file while playing.
I have used OBSLIDER to achieve this.Everything is working fine but it is not as smooth as Apple Default Player.Below is the code what i have used.
Please help me out in this.

```
-(IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender
{
    //player is object of MPMusicPlayerController
    //total seconds is total length of song that is playing in player
    if(self.slider.value<totalseconds)
    {
        [playbackTimer invalidate];
       [self.player setCurrentPlaybackTime:slider.value];
        NSNumberFormatter *percentFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [percentFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];        
        self.labelScrubbing.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Scrubbing speed: %@",
                                    [percentFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.slider.scrubbingSpeed]]];
       //to update the time when slider moves
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
            float totalDuration=slider.value;
            float mins = floor(totalDuration/60);
            float secs = round(totalDuration - mins * 60);
            int roundedSecs = lroundf(secs);
            int roundedMins = lroundf(mins);

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSString *timeInfoString = [[NSString alloc]
                                            initWithFormat:@"%0d.%02d",
                                            roundedMins, roundedSecs];
                currrentDurationSong.text=timeInfoString;
  });

        });

        playbackTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                         target:self
                                                       selector:@selector(updateTime)
                                                       userInfo:nil
                                                        repeats:YES];

    }
    else if(self.slider.value>=totalseconds){

    }

}
```

I used timer to update the time remaining,here is the code for that

```
-(void)updateTime
{

    NSTimeInterval currentProgress = self.player.currentPlaybackTime;
    self.slider.value = currentProgress;
    NSNumberFormatter *percentFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [percentFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];
    self.labelScrubbing.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Scrubbing speed: %@",
                                [percentFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.slider.scrubbingSpeed]]];
    MPMediaItem *nowPlayingMediaItem = [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem];
    NSString* title = [nowPlayingMediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] ;
    NSString* artist = [nowPlayingMediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] ;
      NSString* albumname = [nowPlayingMediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle] ;
    NSString *duration=[nowPlayingMediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
    float totalDuration=[duration floatValue];
    float mins = floor(totalDuration/60);
    float secs = round(totalDuration - mins * 60);
    int roundedSecs = lroundf(secs);
    int roundedMins = lroundf(mins);
    NSLog(@"%02d",roundedMins);


    NSString* _albumString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",(albumname.length>0 ? albumname : @"Unknown") ];
    NSString* _artistString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",(artist.length>0 ? artist : @"Unknown") ];

    NSString *timeInfoString = [[NSString alloc]
                                initWithFormat:@"%0d.%02d",
                                roundedMins, roundedSecs];
    totalDurationSong.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",timeInfoString];
    titleOfSong.text=title;
    ArtistOfSong.text=_artistString;
    albumNameofSong.text=_albumString;
    float min = floor(currentProgress/60);
    float sec = round(currentProgress - min * 60);
    int roundedSec = lroundf(sec);
    int roundedMin = lroundf(min);
    NSString *timeInfoStrings = [[NSString alloc]
                                 initWithFormat:@"%0d.%02d",
                                 roundedMin, roundedSec];
    currrentDurationSong.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",timeInfoStrings];

    if(min+sec==totalseconds){

        [playbackTimer invalidate];
    }


}
```

Comment: @Rajneesh071 i have remove that also,but then also it is not as smooth as Default Player in Apple.I have used that just to make the UILabel to update the time.

Comment: what the mean of using playbackTimer?

Comment: playback timer is to update the song duration left time.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with the same issue. The problem lies in currentPlaybackTime. currentPlaybackTime is limited to sending the current time data every second. So no matter how fast the timer cycles, it will only update the slider every second. However, since your timer is set to 1 second, it may fire offset of the currentPlaybackTime (causing a bit of a stutter). You may want to speed up the time like this:

```
playbackTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                                         target:self
                                                       selector:@selector(updateTime)
                                                       userInfo:nil
                                                        repeats:YES];
```